# Mongoose query for update object with nested arrays

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I have this schema:

```
var controlAgenciesAndObjectsFiltersSchema = new Schema({
  userId: { type: Schema.Types.Number },
  controlAgencyName: { type: Schema.Types.Array, default: [] },
  controlAgencyType: { type: Schema.Types.Array, default: [] },
  inn: { type: Schema.Types.Array, default: [] },
  ogrn: { type: Schema.Types.Array, default: [] },
  licenseNumber: { type: Schema.Types.Array, default: [] },
  licenseNumberRegDate: { type: Schema.Types.Array, default: [] },
  street: { type: Schema.Types.Array, default: [] },
  house: { type: Schema.Types.Array, default: [] },
  housing: { type: Schema.Types.Array, default: [] },
  building: { type: Schema.Types.Array, default: [] },
  contractNumberAndDate: { type: Schema.Types.Array, default: [] },
  controlStartDate: { type: Schema.Types.Array, default: [] },
  controlEndDate: { type: Schema.Types.Array, default: [] },
  houseType: { type: Schema.Types.Array, default: [] },
  cadastralNumber: { type: Schema.Types.Array, default: [] },
  constructionYear: { type: Schema.Types.Array, default: [] },
  commissioningYear: { type: Schema.Types.Array, default: [] },
  houseCondition: { type: Schema.Types.Array, default: [] },
  houseRunOutInPercents: { type: Schema.Types.Array, default: [] },
  houseSeriesAndProjectType: { type: Schema.Types.Array, default: [] },
  houseTotalArea: { type: Schema.Types.Array, default: [] },
  houseResidentalArea: { type: Schema.Types.Array, default: [] },
  interiorWallsType: { type: Schema.Types.Array, default: [] },
  energyEfficiencyClass: { type: Schema.Types.Array, default: [] },
  energyInspectionDate: { type: Schema.Types.Array, default: [] },
}, {
  minimize: false,
  versionKey: false
});
```

I receive new confing for my filters for example this object:

```
{
"inn": [
  {
    "name": "inn",
    "sValue1": "1",
    "sValue2": "",
    "sOperation": "Contains",
    "bExclude": false
  },
  {
    "name": "inn",
    "sValue1": "2",
    "sValue2": "",
    "sOperation": "Contains",
    "bExclude": false
  }
]
}
```

then perform this function

```
function updateCustomConfig (model, response, id, body) {
  model.findOneAndUpdate({ userId: id }, { $set: body }, function (err, doc) {
    if (err) {
      response.send({
        status: "error"
      });
    } else {
      response.send({
        status: "success"
      });
    }
  });
}
```

where id is userId in schema and body is this new json objects with "inn" array. This query is successful but the data which was inserted in a wrong way. I get nested twice array. I expect that data will be replace. but it was embed into consisting empty array and not replaced it.
Wrong is here: http://www.jsoneditoronline.org/?id=251509a941acb4adfe34c8a20414b50f

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `Array` type instead of `Schema.Types.Array` :

```
var controlAgenciesAndObjectsFiltersSchema = new Schema({
    userId: { type: Schema.Types.Number },
    inn: { type : Array , "default" : [] }
});
```

or create an `inn` `Schema` and define an array of it :

```
var innSchema = new Schema({

    "name": String,
    "sValue1": String,
    "sValue2": String,
    "sOperation": String,
    "bExclude": Boolean

}, { _id: false });

var controlAgenciesAndObjectsFiltersSchema = new Schema({
    userId: { type: Schema.Types.Number },
    inn: [innSchema]
});
```

Comment: thanks! Array instead Schema.Types.Array helped me a lot! Can you explain this? Why this works?

Comment: Honestly, I don't know why `Schema.Types.Array` doesnt behave like `Array` as a type. From the doc http://mongoosejs.com/docs/schematypes.html, there is no usage of `Schema.Types.Array`. So, I guess `Schema.Types.Array` should be used internally within mongoose module as well as `Schema.Types.DocumentArray`

Answer (score 0):

Why `findAndUpdate`

Just try with `update`. It's working fine for me

```
function updateCustomConfig (model, response, id, body) {
  model.update({ userId: id }, body, function (err, doc) {
    if (err) {
      response.send({
        status: "error"
      });
    } else {
      response.send({
        status: "success"
      });
    }
  });
}
```

Read more from [here](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/2.7.x/docs/updating-documents.html) about